# Is there any way to enable Email alertes in scdf

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using latest version of speing cloud data flow. Like to enable email alerts when an event occur in SCDF.
Is there any way we can customize or configure it with inbuit functionality in scdf or with stream.

Check document of scdf but nothing mentioned there

Answer (score 0):

The closest things to events that SCDF emits is

1. task / batch events https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-events
2. audit info
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard-auditing

However, they are both ultimately written to the DB though w/ no mechanism for listening to the events in code (or acting upon them). FWIW, the audit info can be retrieved by a secured web endpoint under `/audit-records`.